# User Expectations - Changing the country, currency and language to reflect their locale

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation

Scenario:

You're a customer from Germany, and you've landed on the UK, mobile, version of a website. You've discovered that within the main menu, you can change three things - country, currency and language. Please see the screenshot below.

[image: Country Selecter]

You've selected the country you want, the currency you want and the language you want. Once you hit "Update", what would you expect to happen? My thinking is that if the user is in the menu, then the user should remain in the menu after pressing update.

However, a colleague has suggested that the user should return to the homepage as there may be deals that are related to their locale that they could miss.

Thoughts?

Comment: Where it's a separate 'page', _I_ would expect to be returned to the page from which I came to this selector. If it's a set of pulldowns on a product page (as on e.g., DriveThruRPG), I would expect to stay on the same page, and have any data displayed updated to reflect the new choices (e.g., prices in euro, text in German, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

A language especially is part of how the user interacts not just on the web, but in the real world that they live in. Any language that is selected by the user should come into force straight away, whether or not you choose to clear that overlay selection items straight away or not, some immediate change to the site I should have thought should be actioned immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Surely, the menu should open as an overlay.

That way it could be opened from any page and return the user back to the original page without any problems. This would also allow for deep links into any page of the site.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with you *if* this was something that the user might want to "try on for size" before leaving the menu. For example, the color theme of the UI. In that case, I appreciate staying in the menu instead of being jolted back to the main UI with my changes applied in case I want to revert back to what it was.

However, in this case, there will likely not be a lot of guessing about the settings I want in this menu (because I know my locale), I want to get rid of it as fast as possible to get back to the interesting part of the app.

Even better, can you detect this kind of mismatch (perhaps based on IP address vs. localized version of the side) and have a pop-up banner at the top that says

> Would you like to go to the German version of this site? [Click here].

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to see where the users goes aften they have hit save? Do they go back? Do they change language again? What is the user supposed to do in that page after he changed the locale settings? I guess when the user hit save you could show him something that the change has been made successfully (animation, confirmation popup..) and you might try maybe to automatically forward the user in the home page automatically after 2 seconds of showing the feedback. In either case check what your user are trying to do with the product, where do they go after hitting save? (Are you logging thise events to discover their behaviors?).

Personally in most cases I have seen usually the user goes back to the home page to check how the system looks like with the new locale settings, so I guess it would be better to forward him in the home page (but this is just my personal overview). Let me know how it goes for you :)

Comment: If you can please rewrite as an answer as opposed to asking so many questions.